# Access Children Through Parent in Django

Tags: python, django, parent, children

Is there a way in Django to add children objects to the parent? I know how to retrieve children given a parent but what I intend to do is to add children to the parent so that they may be displayed in a template. I have a list of parents and each parent needs to be displayed with their children in the template. By default, I don't see in the model where I can store a reference to children in the parent object for a one to many relationship. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean ForeignKey objects when saying about parent  and children?

Comment: Question is incomplete, add needed code blocks

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "question is incomplete".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly you can use [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) field for this. Just add to the Child model:

```
class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children')
```

You can add child for parent in different ways. For example you have some parent `p`. You can add new child like this:

```
child = Child(parent=p)
child.save()
```

Or just using relation:

```
child = Child()
p.children.add(child)
```

If you need to get children you can get them via parent:

```
parent.children.all()
```

Comment: In order for this to work, do I have to explicitly set parent.children using an assignment statement? It doesn't seem to work otherwise simply by defining a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: @Foobar I updated my answer, hope this will help. You can find more details here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/